# req.body is an empty object, express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, express, fetch

Im sending a request to my local server in my react app like this

```
  fetch("http://localhost:4000/signup", {
  method: "POST",
  mode: "no-cors",
  body: JSON.stringify({ name: "Joe", lname: "Doe" }),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
})
```

And the problem is that im getting empty object on the req.body on my local server.

```
app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body);
console.log('post request sent');
```

})

How could i fix it that i could see the content which is being sent from the fetch body?

Comment: did you add body-parser in the app middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have two problems here each of which, by themselves, would cause the symptoms you describe.

First, as per the documentation for [`req.body`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body):

> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as express.json() or express.urlencoded().

You don't seem to have loaded the JSON body-parsing middleware.

Second, you said `mode: "no-cors"` which tells `fetch` to silently ignore any attempts to do anything which would require permission from CORS.

This includes setting the `Content-Type: application/json` header which is needed to trigger the JSON parsing middleware.

So remove `mode: "no-cors"` and add [the `cors` middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to your server-side code.